# LINQ with multiple left join and where clause

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

I have following query, and I am converting it to LINQ.

```
select acq.ACQPub as Prev_ACQPub
     , ve.CompanyID
         , ve.EntityID
         , ve.RoundID
         , ve.EntityName
         , ve.Date
         , ve.RoundTypeCode
         , ve.EventType
         , ve.PostValue_DJVS
         , ve.PostVal
         , ve.PreVal
         , fin.FinanceStat
    from ValuationEvents_PIT_New as ve
    left join Acq_PublicDummy as acq
    on ve.EntityID = acq.EntityID
    left join FinStat_New as fin
    on ve.EntityID = fin.EntityID
    where ve.EventType in('ACQ','LBO')
      and acq.ACQPub is null
```

I wanted to double check if I've done it right or there is a better way of doing it.

Here is my code:

```
return (from ve in valuationEvents where ve.EventType == EventTypes.Acq || ve.EventType == EventTypes.Lbo
                          join acq in acqPublicDummies on ve.EntityId equals acq.EntityID into veAcq
                          from x in veAcq.DefaultIfEmpty() where x != null && x.ACQPub == null
                          join fin in finStats on ve.EntityId equals fin.EntityID into veFin
                          from y in veFin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new AcqResearch
                                     {   PrevAcqPub = x == null ? null : x.ACQPub,                                          
                                         EntityId = ve.EntityId,
                                         CompanyId = ve.CompanyId,
                                         RoundId = ve.RoundId,
                                         Date = ve.Date,
                                         RoundTypeCode = ve.RoundTypeCode,
                                         EventType = ve.EventType.ToString(),
                                         PostValueDjvs = ve.PostMoneyValue,
                                         PostVal = ve.PostVal,
                                         PreVal = ve.PreVal,                                             
                                         FinanceStat = y == null ? null : y.FinanceStat
                                     }).ToList();
```

Since result will be used > 1 times I am returning List instead of IEnumerable.

Also I can't run SQL and compare result of it with LINQ result, since query above runs against of Raw data and LINQ is running after data calculations and additional cleansing process.  So there is no way for me to compare query result with my LINQ result.  I just need to rely that logic is correct.  What is the same is SQL logic and LINQ logic.

Thank you very much for your help and feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to verify that the query is the same, you can look at the SQL that is generated from the linq. there are a few ways of doing this:

- Use SQL Profiler
- Paste the query into LinqPad and view the SQL tab
- Set the Log property on your datacontext

You can then compare the two SQL queries and check for differences.

---

As an aside, in your case the only things I would change are style related - I would move all of the where clauses to just above the select clause, so it is easier to see what filter you are applying. Also, the line

`PrevAcqPub = x == null ? null : x.ACQPub`

Seems like it may as well be

`PrevAcqPub = null`

Since you have already filtered out all x that are null and that have x.ACQPub != null (Same goes for the SQL query).

Comment: thank you very much.  I like your idea about LINQPad, however to view it in SQL tab, expression needs to run first.  I can't just paste code from VS and view how it is translated to SQL.  This is not always the option, like in the example above, where such a big expression that depends on so many objects, I will need to write a lot of code in LINQPad.

Comment: @Vlad If you are just checking the structure of the query then you can substitute the processed collections with the table name - e.g. replace `valuationEvents` with `ValuationEvents_PIT_New`. You can also just dummy up some tables (I did this with your query) in SQLEXPRESS and run the query on them. But I agree that this is less than ideal - SQLProfiler is the easier option in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks correct to me